I don't understand the solution of combinatorics problem about a raffle
Problem
I am trying to solve the following math problem:

A local fraternity is conducting a raffle where 50 tickets are to be sold—one per customer.
There are three prizes to be awarded. If the four organizers of the raffle each buy one ticket,
what is the probability that the four organizers win:
a) all of the prizes?
b) exactly two of the prizes?
c) exactly one of the prizes?
d) none of the prizes?

I saw the solution here, but I don't understand it.
More specifically, I don't understand why the number of possibilities to select 3 winners is ${50 \choose 3}$ and why the number of possibilities that 4 origanizers win all the prizes is ${4 \choose 3}$.
How I tried to solve it
I decided to create a toy example of this problem and reformulated it with smaller numbers:

A local fraternity is conducting a raffle where 6 tickets are to be sold—one per customer.
There are 2 prizes to be awarded. If the 3 organizers of the raffle each buy one ticket,
what is the probability that the four organizers win all of the prizes?

My approach of solving toy example
Here is my approach.
The experiment is choosing random ticket for 3 organizers. The order does not matter, so the sample space $S$ will be:
$S=\{(T_1T_2T_3),(T_1T_2T_4),(T_1T_2T_5),(T_1T_2T_6),(T_1T_3T_4),(T_1T_3T_5),(T_1T_3T_6),(T_1T_4T_5),(T_1T_4T_6),(T_1T_5T_6),(T_2T_3T_4),(T_2T_3T_5),(T_2T_3T_6),(T_2T_4T_5),(T_2T_4T_6),(T_2T_5T_6),(T_3T_4T_5),(T_3T_4T_6),(T_3T_5T_6),(T_4T_5T_6)$}
$n_S=20$
Let A denote the event of interest, when 3 organizers win all the prizes (2 prizes, in this case, let them be $T_1$ and $T_2$):
$A=\{(T_1T_2T_3),(T_1T_2T_4),(T_1T_2T_5),(T_1T_2T_6)\}$
$n_A=4$
$P(A)=n_A/n_S=4/20=1/5$
Ok, this is perfectly understandable.
Trying existing solution (which I don't understand)
Then I tried to follow the approach from the solution, here is how:
${2 \choose 6}=6!/(2!4!)=15$ — the number of possibilities to select 2 winners. There is an example set below that I made to understand the solution:
$ExampleSet = \{(T_1T_2), (T_1T_3),(T_1T_4),(T_1T_5),(T_1T_6),(T_2T_3),(T_2T_4),(T_2T_5),(T_2T_6),(T_3T_4),(T_3T_5),(T_3T_6),(T_4T_5),(T_4T_6),(T_5T_6)\}$
Therefore, it seems to me that it is not number of possibilities to select 2 winners, because there are combinations like $(T_4T_5)$ or $(T_3T_4)$ that are not winning. Or, maybe, I created an incorrect set.
Ok, let's move next.
${3 \choose 2}*{6-3 \choose 2-2}=3!/(2!1!)=3$ — the number of possibilities that 3 organizers win all the prizes.
This is what I don't understand even more. I think this is most difficult part for me.
Recall $ExampleSet$. There was only 1 winning combination: $(T_1T_2)$. But okay, I tried to imagine dividing 3 organizers into groups like this (the order within a group does not matter, as we use combinations):
$T_1T_2|T_3$
$T_1T_3|T_2$
$T_2T_3|T_1$
By $T_3$ I mean any other "not winning" ticket, which may be not necessarily $T_3$.
This division makes some sense, but I don't understand how it relates to $ExampleSet$, where I listed ways of choosing a winner.
Ok, now we have 2 numbers:
$3$ — the number of possibilities that 3 organizers win all the prizes;
$15$ — the number of possibilities to select 2 winners.
Now, all we need to do is to divide $3$ by $15$, so I get $1/5$. Success!
But I don't understand how this solution works and why it works. Could you explain it, please?

You are asking for the solution of part (a)
If three of the four organisers win, there are $\binom43$ ways for three out of four organisers to be the lucky winners, and since there is only one combo of 3 with all winning tickets out of $\binom{50}3$ possible combos,
$$Pr = \binom43\frac{\binom33}{\binom{50}3}=  \frac1{4900}, \approx 0.000204$$
PS:
Having understood the approach to the larger problem, you should be able to solve the toy problem easily. In case you have trouble, let me know.
The whole idea of combinatorics is to  solve such problems without actual listing.  !
Btw, you need to correct the typo in your toy problem, you have started with 3 organisers, but are distributing prizes to 4 organisers

Your solution is a different approach to the official one, but equally valid and simplifies to the same answer.
Let's say there are $n$ tickets, $k$ prizes and $r$ organisers, with $n>r>k$.
What you have done is to label the tickets so that the prizes are $T_1,\ldots,T_k$. Then you have considered the number of ways to assign tickets to organisers (unordered), of which there are $\binom nr$. Now the number of these which include all the prizes is $\binom{n-k}{r-k}$, since they must include the first $k$ and any $r-k$ of the remaining $n-k$. So the probability is $$\frac{\frac{(n-k)!}{(r-k)!(n-r)!}}{\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}}=\frac{r\cdot(r-1)\cdots(r-k+1)}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}.$$

The official solution is to label the tickets so that the organisers get $T_1,\ldots,T_r$. Then they considered the number of ways to choose which tickets get prizes. There are $\binom nk$ ways to do this, and the number of ways where all prizes are won by organisers, i.e. are chosen from the first $r$ tickets, is $\binom rk$. So the probability is
$$\frac{\frac{r!}{k!(r-k)!}}{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}=\frac{r\cdot(r-1)\cdots(r-k+1)}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}.$$
